# How to set PWM frequency with high granuality

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, stm32, timer

I want to create a PWM at **100kHz** that can have 1000 steps. e.g. when I set CCR1 to 0%, the PWM is off an when I set CCR1 to 499 it should be 50% and obviously at CCR1 = 999, it should be full duty cycle of 100%.

The CPU_CLK is 80MHz...but I can not achieve this. here is my code so far:

```
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_CENTERALIGNED2;
  htim1.Init.Period = 1000-1;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_ENABLE;
```

This gives me a PWM with frequency of 40kHz....far below 100kHz...the Prescalare is already at minimum ...is this impossible to achive?

The chip is STM32L476.

Comment: 100 kHz times 1000 equals 100 MHz. Your maximum clock is 80 MHz. Do you see a problem?

Comment: Read this https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/7e/17/df/9e/5d/04/4b/72/DM00119042.pdf/files/DM00119042.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119042.pdf

Comment: +1 good question because so many people do not understand the limitations concerning resolution ,clock frequency and PWM frquency.

Comment: Normally in wide dynamic range regulators they use PFM + PWM to achieve 60 dB dynamic range

Comment: So, what is more important for you, "high granularity" in the title, or "100 kHz" in the question? Because 16 bit timers can give you 65k resolution, way above 1000 steps.

Comment: @Maple I need exactly 1000 steps at 100kHz...I think it is not possible to do that easy :( I need a a faster chip

Comment: @DEKKER "I need a a faster chip". Or, you can use external PWM generator, like 12 bit M66242P from Mitsubishi, for 4096 steps up to 25MHz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, it's not trivial with a clock of 80 MHz unless you pull off some dithering techniques (see below).

$$\mathcal{f_{clk}}=PWM_{frequqncy}\times2^{steps} $$

In your case, steps required is 10 bits...therefore you need at least a main clock of 100MHz.

The document I linked in my comment, shows some complex ways to achieve this with lower clock rates by dithering and combining more timers(it is quite complex). Here is the [document](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/7e/17/df/9e/5d/04/4b/72/DM00119042.pdf/files/DM00119042.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119042.pdf) by STM itself.

Obviously, Another solution would be using another MCU from the same family with higher clock speeds if your application/budget allows it.